At the end of Summer of '42, why did the lady have sex with the kid?
She was about 30. Her husband was just killed in World War 2. The last thing I would expect is for a grieving widow to have sex with a teenage boy. On top of that, she seduced him, as I remember.
Why did she do it? Did she do it for him or herself? What emotion was she expressing? As an autistic, I can't interpret her behavior at that moment.

If it's not made clear in the film, I think it's intentionally left vague for the audience to interpret. But people have sex for many reasons, and intimacy is an important one.

I dunno if it's just me, but I feel like "it's intentionally left vague for the audience to interpret" would be an acceptable answer to the question, rather than a reason to close the question as being opinion-based. (My personal interpretation would be that grief makes people act irrationally, so even she may not have understood why she did it.)

I did a bit of a tidy up of the comments - which were getting a little out of hand. Apologies if you feel I was a litle over eager

@Miss_Understands I appreciate that you feel the close votes were somehow targeted at you.  I do feel this perception is not particularly fair.  It is not unreasonable for someone to think that something can only be answered by opinion - it doesn't necessarily indicate targeting.  Personally I feel its better to err on the side of allowing a question to remain open and hope there is some decent objective analysis in the answers.

Feel free to reach out to any moderators if you feel you are being treated unfairly

@F1Krazy - My general response if someone says "only the writer could possibly know that" is to say "let's go and ask them, then..."

The Widow Dorothy is extremely vulnerable. She's just learned of the death of her husband and is wracked with grief. She basically uses this (admittedly quite eager) teen boy as a surrogate for her husband.
In the novelisation, the sequence of events is rather clearer, and even includes a few references to her playing make-believe that this is her husband, Pete.

Colors shifted in and out like slides on a microscope, and there was a
small game of Touch and Whisper in which she disappeared from his arms
only to reappear behind him, her hands over his eyes with guess who,
darling, and welcome home. Words took shape in Hermie’s mouth, protest
words, not even words—sounds. But they flew away, unformed, unsaid
random vowels barely strung.
Another room yet familiar, with no boundaries and little dimension.
Just things, to mark well, to remember. A lamp on a small table. A
clock. A vase with fresh flowers. A comb, a book, a letter. The
sprightly patterned bedspread lifting and turning down. Little framed
paintings on the walls, flowers, always flowers. The fluffy pink robe
floating then settling gracefully across the back of the chair. The
new blue shirt likewise on the bedpost, followed and covered by the
white duck trousers. Pink scuffs on the floor, saddle shoes beside
them turned pigeon-toed, an argyle sock tucked neatly into each one.
Now an embroidered pillow buoying up the dear face, the lovely hair in
a spreading compass rose. Dorothy looking up and smiling, speaking
private words, reminding him of things and times that were not his.
Dorothy eyes open, Dorothy eyes closed. Dorothy with urgings and
promises. Dorothy beneath him, tender arms turned steel, warm legs
drawing him down, beyond the velvet tangle, beyond thought, beyond
stopping, beyond his own voice saying, “No right, no right”…for it was
summer and first time and he loved her so. Dorothy. I love you,
Dorothy.

And after the act, the character gives us some insight.

For fully ten minutes he half expected it to slide open so that Oscy
could appear and scream down at him, “Hubba-hubba, did you use a
rubber?” He of course had not used the rubber. The rubber was down the
road, buried without ceremony but now possessing one frightened
mourner. He hoped she wouldn’t become pregnant because that would be
just too cruel. The worst of it was he couldn’t think of anything to
say to her. Like a coward, he had allowed it to happen. He could have
stopped it. He could have brought her to her senses. He could have
slapped her or thrown cold water on her face. Instead, he had done
nothing. And in addition to that, he was now doing nothing. He was
just waiting for the ceiling panel to slide open so that Pete could
drop down on him and slit his throat with a bayonet. But Pete was
dead, so there’d be no leaping out of the attic for Pete, no more of
anything. Hermie glanced over at her, trying not to let her see any
movement on his part, hoping that maybe she’d think he was dead,
wishing that he was.
It was puzzling the way she lay there, under the sheet, just as though
she were on the beach, her face to the sky, her fine nose at just the
right angle. Whatever was in her mind he didn’t even try to guess at.
He just hoped that she wouldn’t feel terrible. He wouldn’t have cared
if she had turned on him and called him everything in the book, just
as long as she wouldn’t feel awful and guilty and rotten.
He thought about saying a few comforting words, telling her that he
had been in situations like that before because men were dying pretty
regularly and—He let the thought drop right there.
He then thought of offering her marriage. At least, if he told her how
much he loved her, maybe she wouldn’t feel so bad or soiled or taken
advantage of. But no words were forthcoming from his giant brain and
so he continued just to lie there, praying for an unseasonable monsoon
or some other kind of instant but relatively painless death because
he, too, wasn’t feeling all that deserving of much more anguish.
He thought of telling her that maybe it was a mistake, that maybe Pete
wasn’t dead, that maybe it was somebody else. The Army often got
things fucked up like that. But he knew that the odds were against
that being the case. Besides, what had that to do with the fact that
he had just finished making love to a war widow who had helplessly
allowed it to happen because she was in no emotional condition to stop
it? No matter how he juggled the situation around in his mind, no
matter how he twisted it or interpreted it or lied about it, he knew
that in the long run, he was going to be worse off than she. She’d
make it in life because she’d one day realize what and how it had
happened. He’d be in trouble because it was his first time, which
meant he’d remember it forever because that’s the way the legend goes.
Plus he’d always remember that in a situation of crisis, his true
character had come to the fore, revealing him to be more interested in
sex than in compassion.


Interestingly, in an interview with the TCPalm.com, Raucher claims that they didn't actually have sex in reality. They took their clothes off, but didn't do the deed.

Herman Raucher (HR): After the 9/11 debacle, a friend sent me a column form the Los Angeles Times, in which they had done research that following 9/11, all over the country there was an increase in sexuality that would probably rival the (babies born due to) the blackout in New York during the ‘60s. And they specifically mentioned, in Summer of ‘42, how that same thing took place.
And I just showed (the article) to everybody.
LHP: Well -
HR: There are statistics that show that when people face loss and face death, one of the ways they resort to, to prove that they are still alive is to have sex.
So, it took 30 years, but I got off the hook finally.
LHP: Up to that point, had you felt in your heart some guilt about this? That perhaps you had taken advantage of her?
HR: No. No, I didn’t at all.
I don’t know what I felt.
Again, because we never consummated it. I, uh, we - we were mostly holding.
You know, in the movie, we let you think what you want.
LHP: Right.
HR: Yes, we had no clothes on, but she thought I was her husband. ... She kept calling me ‘Pete’.
And I was not of a mind to slap her in the face and say, ‘You’ve gotta cut this out.’
I was just going to be Pete as best I could.
LHP: I see.
HR: It was quite a moment for a 14-year-old. I will fess up to that.
And the aftermath of that was, I dated every girl I could find whose name was Dorothy.


hat tip to @OldPadawan for finding an interesting interview.

Just a note, the novel was written based on the screenplay and then released before the movie came out.

@Legion600 - You are technically correct, which is, of course, the very best kind of correct. See edit.
